# Proving unique solution exists for a system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is from Hefferon's Linear Algebra book. I looked at the book
solution, but I want to know if the method I used to solve the problem is
also correct.

For the following system of equations:

$\ ax + by = j$
$\ cx + dy = k$

prove that if $\ ad - bc$ $\ne$ $\ 0$, then the above system of equations has
a unique solution.

To prove this, I assumed that the system of equations has a unique solution when
$\ ad - bc = 0$.

I have the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}

I reduce the above system into echelon form by subtracting a multiple of the
first row form the second row:

\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c-na&d-nb\end{bmatrix}

So $\ c- na = 0$ which means $\ c = na$.

We also know that $\ ad = bc$ or $\ ad = a(nb)$. In that case $\ d = nb$.

But then $\ d-nb = 0$, and the bottom row of the above matrix is all zeros.
There is no unique solution to the above system of equations which means that
my assumption that $\ ad - bc = 0$ is wrong. Therefore, a unique solution
exists only if $\ ad - bc$ $\ne$ $\ 0$.

Is my line of reasoning to prove the question correct?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes correct. Just also argue out the case when say $a=0$

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for confirming. It's good to know my thought process was correct.